# Cannot allocate vector - silent memory usage in R

Tags: r

[Apologies in advance for the average reprex]

This problem has absolutely flummoxed me. I've spent a long time refining code, trying new things, hunting for problems, but am yet to find anyone describing a problem similar to what I'm experiencing.

I'm trying to analyse high resolution data stored across multiple files. The data is saved on to my local drive.

- Each folder consists of a month worth of files
- Within these folders are in .zip containers representing 30-mins of data
- Each of these .zip files contain 6x csv files ~3MB each.
- Naming is logical - i.e. "dataname_YYYYMMDDHHMM.csv", and similar for the .zip files

I've written a function to find all the files for day, iteratively extract data from the csv files, filter for specific variables and then form a single data frame representing one day (~700,00 rows - so hardly huge).

This function works fine for a single day. But I need a year's worth of summary data so I've written some code to run the function across a vector of dates using a 'lapply'/'map' approach.

And this is where things break down. I get part way through the process and then get the dreaded 'cannot allocate a vector' appears. After doing some digging I can see that it's storing a large amount of data in memory, which is invisible to me. I can *see* that there's a problem by using `pryr::mem_used()` or just looking at the system and watching the memory get chewed up. There are no large objects being stored in the environment, but it's clearly there, somewhere. The only way to get rid of it is to restart R.

I *think* it has something to do with the `unz` process - the size of memory allocation roughly matches the sum of the individual 3MB csv files - but I don't know how to stop it, or find where they're being stored to.

If anyone has any suggestions, or even some advice on how to effectively profile my code, I would be very appreciative.

What's most confusing is that I've successfully run the function for a whole month, but now it's giving me issues even pulling a month, so I've stepped down to running a week at a time.

Code snippet below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


function_name <- function(datestring) {
  
  ## Define a list of timestrings to iterate over
  timestring1 <- merge(0:23, 25)
  timestring1 <- sort(str_c(str_pad(timestring1$x, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), timestring1$y))
  timestring2 <- merge(0:23, 55)
  timestring2 <- sort(str_c(str_pad(timestring2$x, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), timestring2$y))
  timestring <- sort(c(timestring1, timestring2))
  rm(timestring1, timestring2)
  
  
  ## Change the working directory based on date
  setwd(str_c(
    working_dir,
    str_sub(datestring, start = 1L, end = 6L) # Change the directory to desired year-month only
  )
  )
  
  
  ## Loop for zip files over a given day (48 files)
  empty_df <- data.frame()
  
  daily_data <- rep(list(empty_df), 48)
  
  for (i in 1:48) {
    
    ## Check the file exists
    if (file.exists(str_c("xxxx", datestring, timestring[i], ".zip")) == FALSE) {
      
      next
      
    } else {
      
      ## Extract a list of all files inside the zipped folder
      file_names <- as.character(unzip(str_c("xxxx", datestring, timestring[i], ".zip"), 
                                       list = TRUE)$Name)
      
      ## Loop for 5-minute files (6 files) within the 48 daily files
      empty_df_two <- data.frame()
      half_hour_data <- rep(list(empty_df_two), 6)
      
      for (j in 1:6) {       
        
        ## Extract each 5-minute csv file
        half_hour_data[[j]] <- read_csv(unz(str_c("xxxx", datestring, timestring[i], ".zip"),
                                            file_names[j]), 
                                        col_names = c("timestamp", "element", "variable", "value", "quality"),
                                        col_types = cols(
                                          col_datetime(),
                                          col_character(),
                                          col_double(),
                                          col_double(),
                                          col_double()
                                        )
        )
        
        half_hour_data[[j]] <- filter(half_hour_data[[j]], element == 32001 | element == 42001)
        
      }
      
      ## Add the half hourly data to the daily data 
      daily_data[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, half_hour_data)
      
    }
    
  }
  
  ## Combine all data at a daily level
  datdata <- do.call(rbind, daily_data)
 
  ## Correct the timestamp to posix
  datdata$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(datdata$timestamp, 
                                  tz = "Australia/Brisbane",
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  
  return(datdata)
  
}




dates <- as.numeric(
  str_replace_all(
    as.character(
      seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by= "days")
    ), "-", ""))

datestring_list <- split(dates, ceiling(seq_along(dates)/7))


for (i in 1:length(datestring_list)) {

  system.time({
    data <- map(datestring_list[[i]], function_name)
  })
  
 data <- do.call(rbind, data)

## Then do some more analysis, summarise and produce results...
```

Comment: I don't know if this is happening to you, but one way to leak memory is to open a connection and not close it.  I'd assign the result of the `unz()` call to a variable, and explicitly close it after the read, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330, that’s where my thinking is currently at. 
I was trying to play around with that concept earlier tonight but unsure how to get it work - my usage of open() and close() didn’t work.